# Codeigniter Where_In Operator Does Return Any Result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter to query a list of result by passing Array into the modal. But the return result alway empty. I had checked and try to a few method that i found on stackoverflow but none of it work.

Eg. 
Array
(
 [0] => 12
 [1] => 13
)

My code :

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sms_model extends CI_Model
{
    //Return Selected Customer ID
    public function getCustomerInfo($data){

        $ids = array();
        foreach ($data['customerID'] as $id)
            {
                $ids[] = $id;
            }
        print_r($ids);
        $this->db->select('Handphone');
        $this->db->from('tblcustomer');
        $this->db->where_in('CustomerID', $ids);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

What did i do wrong on the query?
Please guide me, thanks

Comment: Your code looks fine.  print query by `echo $this->db->last_query();` and test it manually.   And you can delete helpless loop, but say `$this->db->where_in('CustomerID', (array) $data['customerID']);`

Comment: @splash58 I did try before and the result only return the first row. Any solution?

Comment: *But the return result alway empty*, *the result only return the first row* ?

Comment: `if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {` how it can return 2 or more results?

Comment: @splash58 Arg!! Silly me, did not see this small mistake. I changed to   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { and all result returned nicely. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your IF statment, should be > 0 not == 1. You can also remove your foreach.

Like so:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sms_model extends CI_Model
{
    //Return Selected Customer ID
    public function getCustomerInfo($data){

        $this->db->select('Handphone');
        $this->db->from('tblcustomer');
        $this->db->where_in('CustomerID', $data['customerID']);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in your **$this->db** object call. You can follow below code to get result. Check that your column and table exist in your database

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sms_model extends CI_Model
{
    //Return Selected Customer ID
    public function getCustomerInfo($data){


        //print_r($ids);
        //give value for $ids variable
        $this->db->select('Handphone'); 
        $this->db->where('CustomerID', $ids);
        $query = $this->db->get('tblcustomer');

        if ($query ->result_id->num_rows > 0) {
            return $query->result_object();
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```